# Typescript convert JSON to array of JSON

Tags: json, typescript

```
{
    "Id": null,
    "productType": {
        "productname": "abc",
        "productPrice": ""
    }
 }
```

How to convert above JSON to array of Product?

```
{
    "Id": null,
    "product": [{
        "productType": {
            "productname": "abc",
            "productPrice": ""
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Will there always be a single product?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this *actually* a TS question?  Not really sure what's *really* being asked, here.

But if by "how to convert" you mean as a TS type:

original

```
type ProductType = { productName: string, productPrice: string }
type Product = { id: string, productType: ProductType }
```

after

```
type X = { id: string, product: ProductType[] }
```

Comment: my model is a TS class. This helps , Thank you.